# How to connect to mysql inside a Kubernetes cluster?

Tags: java, mysql, kubernetes, jdbc

I have a java app that needs to connect to a MySQL instance running inside a Kubernetes cluster.
The MySQL instance comes up just fine and I can log into the container from the shell.
The configuration looks like:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mysql
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mysql
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mysql
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: mysql
          image: mysql:latest
          env:
            # Use secret in real usage
            - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
              value: password
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3306
              name: mysql
          volumeMounts:
            - name: mysql-persistent-storage
              mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
      volumes:
        - name: mysql-persistent-storage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: mysql-pv-claim
---

apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: mysql-pv-volume
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/mnt/data"
    
---

apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: mysql-pv-claim
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
      
---

  apiVersion: v1
  kind: Service
  metadata:
    name: mysql
  spec:
    type: NodePort
    selector:
      app: mysql
    ports:
      - protocol: TCP
        port: 3306
        nodePort: 30000
        targetPort: 3306
```

My java application is build using Docker and I can run it just fine on localhost; I'm wondering how I can pass in the `db.url` when running the application container?

The YML for the application is as follows:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: directory-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: directory
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: directory
    spec:
      containers:
          - name: directory-container
            image: directory:latest
            imagePullPolicy: Always
            ports:
              - containerPort: 8080
            env:
              - name: SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL
                value: jdbc:mysql://${DB_HOST}/temp?useSSL=false
                
---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: directory-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: directory
  ports:
      - protocol: TCP
        port: 8080
        targetPort: 8080
  type: LoadBalancer
                
---


apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: directory-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: directory-mysql
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: directory-mysql
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: directory
          image: directory:latest
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
          env:   # Setting Enviornmental Variables
            - name: DB_HOST   # Setting Database host address from configMap
              valueFrom :
                configMapKeyRef :
                  name : db-config
                  key :  host

            - name: DB_NAME  # Setting Database name from configMap
              valueFrom :
                configMapKeyRef :
                  name : db-config
                  key :  dbName
            - name: DB_USERNAME  # Setting Database username from Secret
              valueFrom :
                secretKeyRef :
                  name : mysql-secrets
                  key :  username
            - name: DB_PASSWORD # Setting Database password from Secret
              valueFrom :
                secretKeyRef :
                  name : mysql-secrets
                  key :  password

---

apiVersion: v1 # Kubernetes API version
kind: Service # Kubernetes resource kind we are creating
metadata: # Metadata of the resource kind we are creating
  name: directory
spec:
  selector:
    app: mysql
  ports:
    - protocol: "TCP"
      port: 8080 # The port that the service is running on in the cluster
      targetPort: 8080 # The port exposed by the service
  type: NodePort # type of the service.
```

What I'm looking to do is to pass in the correct `db.url` to the application container to connect to the MySQL pod.

**kubectl get svc**

```
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
directory    NodePort    10.101.234.92   <none>        8080:30561/TCP   5m11s
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP          38m
mysql        NodePort    10.96.238.113   <none>        3306:30000/TCP   32m
```

**kubectl get deployments**

```
NAME                   READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
directory-deployment   0/1     1            0           5m18s
mysql                  1/1     1            1           34m
```

As I launch the service; the JDBC connector is trying to use `jdbc:mysql://mysql/temp` but as you can see, it won't connect

```
java -jar ./target/Test.jar
[main] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.util.log - Logging initialized @56ms
[main] INFO org.test.db.DatabaseConfig - DB url: jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306
[main] INFO org.test.db.DatabaseConfig - Loaded the db file correctly!!!
[main] INFO org.test.db.DatabaseConfig - DB url: jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306
[main] ERROR org.test.handlers.Directory - The database does now exist!!!!
Exception in thread "main" com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

1) [Guice/ErrorInjectingConstructor]: RuntimeException: Cannot connect to DB; Communications link failure
```

Comment: The Service's name `mysql` is usable as a host name from other Pods in the same namespace.

Comment: As I launch the service; the JDBC connector is trying to use ```jdbc:mysql://mysql/temp``` but as you can see, it won't connect

Comment: Did you specify the database name? `jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/DB_NAME`

Comment: On starting mysql:

```kubectl exec --stdin --tty mysql-587f8bc4f7-fwnvh -- /bin/bash```
```
bash-4.4# mysql -ppassword

Your MySQL connection id is 9
Server version: 8.3.0 MySQL Community Server - GPL


Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> show databases
    -> ;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| sys                |
+--------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: kubectl get svc
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1      <none>        443/TCP          6m44s
mysql        NodePort    10.101.40.82   <none>        3306:30000/TCP   3m36s

Comment: kubectl get pods
NAME                                    READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
directory-deployment-7bcf7d9948-9t9l9   0/1     ImagePullBackOff   0          78s
mysql-587f8bc4f7-fwnvh                  1/1     Running            0          6m39s

Comment: main] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.util.log - Logging initialized @91ms
[main] INFO org.personio.db.DatabaseConfig - DB url: jdbc:mysql://mysql/temp?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
[main] INFO org.personio.db.DatabaseConfig - Loaded the db file correctly!!!
[main] INFO org.personio.db.DatabaseConfig - DB url: jdbc:mysql://mysql/temp?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
[main] ERROR org.personio.handlers.Directory - The database does now exist!!!!

Comment: ```> kubectl get pods
NAME                     READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
mysql-587f8bc4f7-tv87m   1/1     Running   0          2m48s
   

 > kubectl get svc
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP          5m27s
mysql        NodePort    10.111.117.140   <none>        3306:30000/TCP   2m45s
```